# Convert curl method into python request

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to convert a curl method into a python `POST` request.

Here is the curl command:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://global.kaleyra.com/api/v4/' --form 'file=@/home/user/Desktop/TWP_MD565041.pdf' --form 'method=wa' --form 'api_key=A3d51xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' --form 'from=971xxxxxxxxxx' --form 'body={
 "to":"9198xxxxxxxx",
 "type": "document", "document" : {"caption" : ""},
  "callback":""
   }' --form 'format=json'
```

And here is the python request ia tried:

```
payload = {
             "method": "wa",
             "api_key": "A3dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
             "body": '{"to":'+str(user_number)+',"type": "document"}',
             'from': '971xxxxxxxx',
             'format':'json',
             "file":open("/home/user/Desktop/TWP_MD565041.pdf","rb")}
r = requests.post(url=api_url,headers={}, files=payload)
```

getting error:

> b'{"status":"A401B","message":"Method Not Found"}'

Then i changed request like this:

```
    r = requests.post(url=api_url,headers={}, files=json.dumps(payload))
```

Now am getting an error:

> TypeError: Object of type 'BufferedReader' is not JSON serializable

And i tried this,

```
with open("/home/user/Desktop/TWP_MD565041.pdf",'rb') as f:

        r = session.post(url=api_url,headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload),files={"file":f})
```

Then i an getting an error:

> ValueError: Data must not be a string.

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

1) Requests will serialize the JSON for you. Drop the json.dumps method and use the raw payload.

2) I suggest sending the file as such. The with statement is used for larger atomic manipulations, and you really don't need to keep the file open while performing API I/O. Therefore, use the following method, as the file stream is implicitly closed after interpretation.

```
r = session.post(
    url = api_url,
    headers = headers, 
    data = payload,
    files = {'file': open('file.pdf','rb')}
)
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but getting this error `ValueError: Data must not be a string.`
here is the request. `r = session.post(url=api_url,headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload),files={"file":open("/home/user/Desktop/TWP_MD565041.pdf","rb")})`

if i remove `json.dumps()` from data part. i am getting reponse like : b'{"status":"A401B","message":"Method Not Found"}'

Comment: So we fixed the answer you originally asked the question for. This new question has to do with your API. Make sure that you are interacting with it correctly. Read the documentation and determine how to structure the posted data.